# Single-crossing of functions involving random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider two random variables that are jointly normally distributed: 
$$
(T,C)\sim \text{BiNormal}[(\mu_t,\mu_c),(\sigma_t,\sigma_c),\rho]
$$

Now let me define two functions:

$$
\alpha(c)\equiv\Pr[T>a|C=c]
$$
for some scalar $a$. And

$$
k(c)\equiv \frac{c}{b}
$$
for some positive scalar $b$.

Is it the case that $\alpha(c)$ and $k(c)$ cross at most once as $c$ traverses from $0$ to infinity?

I have run simulations and this seems to be the case. It must certainly be true if $\rho<0$, since in such case $\alpha(c)$ is non-increasing in $c$. But is it more generally true for any $\rho$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$T|C = c \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu_T + \frac {\sigma_T} {\sigma_C} \rho (c - \mu_C), (1 - \rho^2)\sigma_T^2\right)$$

Consider the function

$$ \alpha(c) - k(c) \triangleq \Pr\{T > a|C = c\} - \frac {c} {b} 
= 1 - \Phi\left(\frac {\displaystyle a - \mu_T - \frac {\sigma_T} {\sigma_C} \rho (c - \mu_C)} { \sqrt{1 - \rho^2}\sigma_T}\right) - \frac {c} {b}$$

The number of crossings is equal to the number of roots of the above functions. Differentiate with respect to $c$, we have

$$ \alpha'(c) - k'(c) =  \frac {\rho} {\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}\sigma_C}
\exp\left\{- \frac {\displaystyle \left[a - \mu_T - \frac {\sigma_T} {\sigma_C} \rho (c - \mu_C)\right]^2} { 2(1 - \rho^2)\sigma_T^2}\right\}  - \frac {1} {b}$$

When $\rho < 0$, the derivative is always negative, i.e. $\alpha(c) - k(c)$ is always decreasing. Since $\Phi$ is bounded and the linear part dominate, it is easy to see that $\alpha(c) - k(c) \to +\infty$ as $c \to -\infty$, and $\alpha(c) - k(c) \to -\infty$ as $c \to +\infty$. As $\alpha(c) - k(c)$ is a continuous function, by intermediate value theorem, there exist one root, and by the monotonicity, the root is unique.

When $\rho = 0$ it is similar - the function just reduced to a linear function in $c$ so the root is unique again.

When $\rho > 0$, note that the exponential function is bounded above by $1$. So when
$$ \frac {\rho} {\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}\sigma_C} - \frac {1} {b} < 0 \iff b < \frac {\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}\sigma_C} {\rho}$$
the derivative is still always negative and thus reduce to the similar analysis as above.

Otherwise, $\alpha'(c) - k'(c)$ will have two zeros, namely
$$ \frac {\sigma_C} {\sigma_T\rho} \left[a - \mu_T + \frac {\sigma_T} {\sigma_C} \mu_C \pm \sqrt{2(1 - \rho^2)\sigma_T^2 \ln\left(\frac {b\rho} {\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}\sigma_C} \right)}\right]$$

We denote the above $2$ numbers as $c_1, c_2$ with $c_1 < c_2$. So when $\alpha(c_1) - k(c_1) < 0$ and $\alpha(c_2) - k(c_2) > 0$, we have $3$ distinct roots. When one of the above two conditions is equal to $0$ only, we have $2$ distinct roots ($1$ repeated), which mean the line $k(c)$ is tangent to  $\alpha(c)$ at that point. Otherwise it still has one root only.

I am not going to simplify the condition (and I doubt if it can be). Here is just providing a simple illustration with 
$$\rho = \frac {1} {2}, \sigma_C = \sigma_T = \frac {1} {\sqrt{3}}, c = \mu_C = \mu_T = 0, a = \frac {3} {4}, b = 3$$
Then
$$ \alpha(c) = 1 - \Phi\left(\frac {3} {2} - c\right) = \Phi\left(c - \frac {3} {2}\right), k(c) = \frac {c} {3}, b = 3 > \sqrt{2\pi} $$

I am not going to verify the two conditions, but just plot $\alpha(c)$ and $k(c)$ out:

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful. It proves existence and provides conditions for uniqueness. That means this also answers a related question that I posted here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2421015/root-of-function-involving-random-variables-proof-of-existence

Comment: It would be great if you can have a look at the related question. And if you post a link to the answer above I will also accept it as an answer to the other question.